# create a new pandas column based on condition in one column and assigning the value from multiple columns in the same data frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I am trying to create a new column based on condition in one column and assigning the value from multiple columns in the same data frame.

Below is the code that i tried.

```
data["Associate"]= data.apply(lambda x: np.where(x.BU=='SBS',x.SBS,x.MAS_NAS_HRO),axis=1)
```

[image]

```
BU    SBS       MAS_NAS_HRO   Associate
SBS   Ren       Sunil         Ren
MAS   Uma       Majid         Majid
NAS   Sumit     Uma           Uma
```

Above image is what i am trying to achieve i get this error:

```
ValueError: Cannot set a frame with no defined index and a value that cannot be converted to a Series
```

I tried also

```
data['Associate']=''
data.loc[data['BU'] == 'SBS',Associate]=data['SBS']
```

I tried this and as well it did not work.

```
associate_details=['SBS']
associate1=data[data.BU.isin(associate_details)]
choice_assoc1=efile_data['SBS']
associate2=data[~data.BU.isin(associate_details)]
choice_assoc2=efile_data['MAS_NAS_HRO']
efile_data['Associate']=np.select([associate1,associate2],[choice_assoc1,choice_assoc2],default=np.nan)

i get this message [0 rows x 4 columns]
Empty DataFrame
```

How do i change these errors.

Regards,
Ren.

Comment: Where's your input data? Can you add it, not as a picture, but in a way we can copy and paste it

Comment: @Erfan i added the same. The BU, SBS, MAS_NAS_HRO are the input columns and the  output column is Assoicate

Comment: You don't need `apply` for this. Simply use: `data['Associate'] = np.where(x['BU']=='SBS',x['SBS'],x['MAS_NAS_HRO'])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why your first piece of code isn't working because it worked for me, but you could try one of the other methods below.

I'm using numpy version 1.16.4 and pandas version 0.24.2 on Python 3.7.3.

```
data = {
    'BU': ['SBS', 'MAS', 'NAS'],
    'SBS': ['Ren', 'Uma', 'Sumit'],
    'MAS_NAS_HRO': ['Sunil', 'Majid', 'Uma']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# The following all work, but I prefer no. 3. It's faster and more concise.

# 1. Using apply with lambda and if statement
df['Associates'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['SBS'] if row['BU'] == 'SBS' else row['MAS_NAS_HRO'], axis=1)

# 2. Using apply with lambda and np.where (op's method)
df["Associate"] = df.apply(lambda x: np.where(x.BU=='SBS', x.SBS, x.MAS_NAS_HRO), axis=1)

# 3. Using np.where only (s/o to @Erfan)
df['Associate'] = np.where(df['BU']=='SBS', df['SBS'], df['MAS_NAS_HRO'])
```

Comment: Thanks Onel, what i noticed is that both my codes and your had crashed initially due  to an additional white space being present in the BU column